# Delete file using uri extracted from MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA

Tags: android, mediastore

Before marking this question as duplicate i wanna say that i had visited many similar questions but none of them had solved my problem.So, i had extracted all audio files from internal storage using MediaStore and stored its Uri in string form but later when i try to use file.delete using that Uri to delete the audio, former is returning false. 
Following goes the code for extracting song uri and its working properly:

```
    Uri uri= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection=MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"!=0";
    Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,selection,null,null);
    if(c!=null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();

        do {
            String audioName=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String artist=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String album=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String url=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String size=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE));

            audioInfoArrayList.add(new AudioInfo(url,audioName,artist,album));

        }while (c.moveToNext());

        c.close();
```

Here, i had stored all the retrieved information about audio in arrayList of a custom type which also stores above extracted uri in string form which could be extracted using getUrl() method.
Following goes the code how i'am trying to delete it:

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse(audioInfo.get(position).getUrl()); //its actually returning the url stored above in string form
deleteFile(uri.getPath());
Log.i("logText","uri.getPath() : "+uri.getPath());
Log.i("logText","audioInfo.get(position).getUrl() : "+audioInfo.get(position).getUrl());
```

deleteFile function:

```
public void deleteFile(String filePath){
    if(filePath.startsWith("content://")){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.delete(Uri.parse(filePath), null, null);
    }else {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            if (file.delete()) {
                Log.e("logText", "File deleted."); //condition 0
            }else {
                Log.e("logText", "Failed to delete file!");  //condition 1
            }
        }else {
            Log.e("logText", "File not exist!"); //condition 2
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my logcat for a sample audio file:

> ```
> 01-11 13:52:34.257 19982-19982/com.example.hp.myplayer E/logText: Failed to delete file!
> 01-11 13:52:34.257 19982-19982/com.example.hp.myplayer I/logText: uri.getPath() : /storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/Copy Copy Fireflies-Owl_City[www.Mp3MaD.Com].mp3
> 01-11 13:52:34.257 19982-19982/com.example.hp.myplayer I/logText: audioInfo.get(position).getUrl() : /storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/Copy Copy Fireflies-Owl_City[www.Mp3MaD.Com].mp3
> ```

**Note:** On calling deleteFile() condition 1 is executed not 2 or 0 which according to me means that file is being located using that uri in the storage but can't be deleted and file.delete() is returning false.

Comment: Please show an uri you extracted. Give the value of uri.toString().

Comment: You start wit a cursor c. But you omitted how you got the cursor. Shkw cimplete code please.

Comment: `void deleteFile()`. You should make that `boolean deleteFile()` and check the return value.

Comment: delete function inside deleteFile is returning false. greenapps  i am uploading the full code of that cursor part

Comment: @greenapps i had updated the question

Comment: `if(file.exists()) `. What is the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` there? You should log it together with the failed message.

Comment: `On calling deleteFile() condition 1 is executed not 2 or 0 ` ????? What are you talking about? I cannot follow you. Cant you even start telling if the content scheme is used?

Comment: `delete function inside deleteFile is returning false.`. Not very helpfull. You have two delete functions there. How should we know where you are taking about?

Comment: In deleteFile i had marlked conditions 0, 1,2 as comments, please review and condition 1 is executed that means it is going in if(file. exists)

Comment: Those are not conditions but log statements. And further you are not giving the info i ask for. Your post is a mess. I try to discover what happens but you manage to make that very difficult.

Comment: Have you used a file explorer app on your device to check if the file exists in that directory?

Comment: Okay.. I dont know much about content scheme and file. GetAbsolutePath() is returning same string uri.getPath

Comment: Yes.. That file exists and i could play it using  media player

Comment: So.. And now i have to look what the value of uri.getPath() would be. Why so lazy and not mention the path? Not very help full.

Comment: I do not understand that you are even talking about a media store. Your only problem is that you can not delete a file in external storage. You could have written a very different post to begin with.

Comment: And if you cannot delete a file from that directory then did you try to create a file or subdir in that directory? To check if you have write access. What did you do to obtain write access?

Comment: uri.toString() : /storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/Copy Copy Fireflies-Owl_City[www.Mp3MaD.Com].mp3    file.getPath() : file.getPath() /storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/Copy Copy Fireflies-Owl_City[www.Mp3MaD.Com].mp3  file.getAbsolutePath() : file.getPath() /storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/Copy Copy Fireflies-Owl_City[www.Mp3MaD.Com].mp3 all three return same string

Comment: writing on externaldisk could also be the problem, i am checking by creating subdirectory

Comment: I think it could be the main problem that i cant alter external storage contents because file from subdirectory is also not deleted

Comment: Unclear! Then could you create a subdirectory in that directory? And also create a file in that subdirectory?

Comment: But i  dont know if we require a permission for write access in drive. In mainifest i had asked for permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: That is not enough if you are on Android 6+.

Comment: Yes.. I am working on noughat and minimum sdk requirement for my app is 19. Do i require another permission or some other kinda stuff too??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting for read and write external storage permission in manifest is not enough for Android 6 and above.

You should add code to ask the user of your app to confirm the requested permissions.

Google for runtime permissions.